# How to use the Simplex-method for constraints which are given as equations?

Tags: optimization, simplex

I got stuck with the solution of an optimization problem which I have to solve. I read a lot about how to use the simplex method  and I can successfully apply it when the constraints are of the type "<= " or "<" , but I don't manage to understand how to use the method when I have equations instead.
[image: For example :]

Could someone explain to me how to make my Simplex table and how to solve it step by step? Thank you very much !

Comment: In this case, you don't need slack variables. The difficulty comes from the fact that it may be difficult to find an initial solution for your simplex. So you need to introduce artificial variables and proceed in 2 phases. You must have seen this in class.

Comment: How to do it in 2 phases ? An initial solution would be (1,1,4,0,0) ,but how to go further?

Comment: If you have an initial solution, you do not need the 2 phase approach. In this case juste start your table simplex like you would normally do (except for the fact that you don't have slack variables).

Answer (score 0):

You can transform equality constraints to inequality constraints. A constraint like $x=5$ can be written as two constraints: $$x \leq 5 \\ x\geq5 $$.
These two constraints will force x to equal 5.
Your first constraint can thus be written as the following two inequality constraints:
$$ x_1 -2x_4 +4x_5 \leq 1 \\
 x_1 -2x_4 +4 x_5 \geq 1$$.

Multiplying the second constraint by -1 will bring it into the form $\leq$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at the problem is by noticing that the constraints are equivalent to
\begin{cases}
-2x_4+4x_5 &\le 1 \\
x_4 &\le 1 \\
3x_4+2x_5 &\le 4
\end{cases}
In other words, you can consider that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are your slack variables (with non null coefficients in the objective function).

In this case, the initial solution consists in setting variables $x_4$ and $x_5$ to $0$, which yields $X_0 =(1,1,4,0,0)$ which is the initial solution that you proposed.

Now, start your table simplex like you usually would. In the first iteration, $x_4$ is the entering variable (with reduced cost $10$), and $x_2$ exits. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I really have no idea how to make the table ... I watched this video a couple of times :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVzjXpwW2xI

Comment: Ok...have you studied the simplex method in class? And are you able to perform simpler examples on your own?

Comment: not in class ,just from videos an materials from the internet. I used this:
http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s3.pdf